# Trying to install unity editor from unity hub

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I can't install the unity editor from unity hub.

Whenever I try to quote on "add" a unity editor to download, I clock and agree for the whole thing but I don't see any sign of downloading when I return to the unity hub screen.

I dont know what is happening is it supposed to be like this?

Comment: Someone after you posted issues with installing unity from hub, so Im guessing unity have an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it might be a bug or network problem, but you can download unity editor manually :
https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive

[image: unity3d editor download]